# From start date to end date, print the count of a third variable

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a start date as current date, which is stored in an array and the date 5 days back which is the end date.

Suppose the start date is 2014-12-03 and end date is 2014-11-28, so I have to print the count of a variable resulting from foreach, `$value->user_source_history_date`

And the process should run till the defined number lets say 30, where there are 30 dates in an array.

```
for($i=0; $i<=30; $i++)
{
$temp = strtotime("-5 days")
$dates = date("Y-m-d" , $temp)

}
```

Here I am iterating through 30 days, to get blocks of 5 days.

Lets say from a start date and end date, in the database field, user_source_history_dates, there are some 10 entries. So I need that count i.e 10
And the entries look like this:

```
2014-12-02 16:07:42
2014-12-02 16:07:42
2014-12-02 16:07:42
2014-12-02 16:07:42
2014-11-29 13:22:31
2014-11-29 13:22:31
2014-11-29 13:22:31
```

The start date would be 2014-12-03 and the end date would be 2014-11-28. So from the data above, I should get the count as 7.

My problem is how should I increment the count of `$value->user_source_history_date`

Also one of the problem is when the loop iterates, the end date previous iteration **should become** start date of next iteration.

One thing that I can do is use SQL query to get the data from a particular date block. Say something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE datum BETWEEN '2011-4-6' AND '2011-4-12';
```

Comment: not clear, can you describe more?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: What is that: `$i<=30`? Anyway, at for, you are using `,` instead of `;`. Edit the code please. Why do not just loop through the records, and count them? Or you can use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table ...`

Comment: @lolka_bolka I just typed in here, typing mistake or out of my wits. Anyways, so the problem is if it is in loop, the second time the loop runs, the end date of previous iteration becomes start date of the current iteration.

Comment: Because you are always overwrite the `$dates` variable. check my answer.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Please check the question again.

Comment: Then i really don't get it what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP comment, I hope I undersood him:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $temp = strtotime("-5 days");
    //Store dates in an array
    $dates[] = date("Y-m-d", $temp);
}
echo "The cound of dates: " . count($dates)."<br />";
var_dump($dates);
```

Comment: But that would just give me a count 10.